# Statistically comparing surface slope of 2 different areas?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, statistics, slope

I could use the statistical tests like t-test and ANOVA, however I am afraid those test will easily show significant differences if I use the slope values of all cells from each area.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Please [edit] your question/tags to include that information.

Comment: What about the basic summary stats like `min`, `max`, `mean`, `variance`, `std` etc.  Are you starting with elevation values, or actual slope values?

Comment: I am using slope values

Comment: Please tell us *why* you are comparing the slopes.  What do you hope to achieve with this comparison?  What is it intended to represent?

Comment: I would like to be able to say if one are is different from the other, on slope wise!